# Creating a regex to check number of occurence

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I want to check how many times this sequence occurs in a webpage in UFT (012345). Basically any 6 digits in between left parenthesis and right parenthesis. I want to figure out how times this (012345) occurs in the page.

What I have so far is:

```
Set myReg = new regexp
myReg.pattern = '(' [0-9]+ ')'
Set k = Browser("My Webpage).Page("My Index").ChildObjects(myReg)
msgbox k.count
```

This doesn't work. Could someone put me in the right path?

Answer (score 1):

Read reference:

- [Regular Expression Syntax (Scripting)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x(v=vs.84).aspx) and
- [Regular Expression Object Properties and Methods (VBScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxt24tyh(v=vs.84).aspx)

Next *pure* `VBScript` code snippet could help:

```
  sText = "(123456) (123) (abcdef)"   ' !!! retrieve web page source text here !!!
                                      '     instead of testing sample

  Set regEx        = New RegExp       ' Create regular expression
  regEx.Pattern    = "\([0-9]{6}\)"   ' Set pattern
  regEx.IgnoreCase = True             ' Set case sensitivity: superabundant for numbers
  regEx.Global     = True             ' Set global applicability: all occurrences
  Set oMatches = regEx.Execute(sText) ' Execute search
  RegExpCountr = oMatches.Count       ' 
  msgbox RegExpCountr
```